# ERROR while installing Adafruit-DHT in rasperry pi 4

Tags: pip, adafruit

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Adafruit_DHT
Using cached Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
Building wheel for Adafruit_DHT (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Ã— python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
â”‚ exit code: 1
â•°â”€> [1 lines of output]
Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Adafruit_DHT
Running setup.py clean for Adafruit_DHT
Failed to build Adafruit_DHT
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Adafruit_DHT, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried many youtube videos.BUT I COULDN'T GET ANY SOLUTION.
I EXPECT TO SOLVE THIS ERROR